# jQueryUI dialog not working in page loaded via jQuery.load

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I tried the sample code for the jQuery UI dialog and got it to work -- saved that file as page1.html. That works, however, when I tried to load that page via jQuery.load to a container div (data-container) of a PHP page, page1 won't work, even displaying everything that's supposed to be hidden.

Both pages has its set of css and js. Is there a way for those css/js not get in the way of each other's pages? or is it when you use jquery's load function, the loaded page makes use of the parent's (PHP page) loaded css/js? If this is the case, how do I fix this concern of mine?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to initialize dialog after load. Try this `$('#data-container').load('page1.html', function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});`

Answer (score 0):

Got it! After taking the advise made by anpsmn in the above comment, because it still didn't work after that, what I did was, I moved the css/js references for the dialog in page1.html to the parent page (PHP page).

So, the js containing this code:

```
$('#data-container').load('page1.html', function() { $( "#dialog" ).dialog(<my dialog stuff>); });
```

was moved to be referenced from the parent page (PHP page) rather than in page1.html. I think it makes sense since the dialog IS initialized after the page (page1.html) was loaded in the parent page.

Thanks for making my first question here a good experience. Hope to learn more and hopefully get to answer a question and then some. ^^;